# Access 2003 Database column split in multi column Vb.net listview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need Help to load Access Data in listview.
Access2003 One column Data load two clumn As like Date time using sliit.

Column Example:
|logid     | logtime                |
|01271000  | 04/02/2014 08:02:04 AM |
|01271000  | 04/02/2014 06:08:10 PM |
|01271000  | 05/02/2014 08:05:14 AM |
|01271000  | 05/02/2014 06:02:34 PM |

I need to View in ListView as like this:

Logid  | Logtime    | Time_AM     |  Time_PM    |
01271  | 04/02/2014 | 08:02:04 AM | 06:08:10 PM |
01271  | 05/02/2014 | 08:05:14 AM | 06:02:34 PM |

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a very similar structure to your data.

[image]

The SQL below will yield this result:

[image]

Note that this is "Access SQL" so you would create a view with this in Access and then connect your ListView to the view.

```
SELECT Table1.MyID, Table1.Logtime, Table1_1.Logtime, 
 Format([Table1].[Logtime],"yyyy-mm-dd")  AS Dt,
 Format([Table1].[Logtime],"hh:nn:ss AM/PM") AS DtTime, 
 Format([Table1_1].[Logtime],"yyyy-mm-dd") AS Dt1, 
 Format([Table1_1].[Logtime],"hh:nn:ss AM/PM") AS DtTime1
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.MyID = Table1_1.MyID
WHERE (((Table1.Logtime)<>[Table1_1].[Logtime]) AND ((Table1_1.Logtime)>[Table1].[Logtime]));
```